# Facebook SDK on IntelliJ IDEA won't work

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk

I have downloaded the latest facebook SDK version 3.7.
Unfortunately I'm unable to import the project correctly:

-If I try to import the whole directory (is seen as gradle project by the IDE)... get error `incorrect Gradle version edit setting` and project isn't imported correctly. I have used default setting and with other projects usually works.

-If I try to import a single sample Project, get various compilation errors because doesn't find support library. If I add the library, seems compile but ad the end fails and I get an error `Unable to execute dex`.

What is the right way to use Facebook libs and sample with IntelliJ IDEA?

Comment: Out of curiosity, did you try importing the projects from the Facebook project as existing source? I was not able to import the projects using the IntelliJ Gradle wrapper with the Gradle files they provided with the SDK. I actually had to import the existing source files in both the example files and the Facebook library project. So, you may just want to try importing the Facebook library project into your app, make sure it's a library project and ensure that as a part of the module settings that it includes the Android Support JAR in the compilation process.

Comment: Is my second attempt, and I get Unable to execute dex :(

Comment: Do you have the conditions and/or logs causing it to not execute dex? or is that the only thing showing up in your console/logs?

Comment: Did you ever manage to get this working?